# Finding duplicate differences between two tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I try to find duplicate rows between two tables. This code works only if records are not duplicated:

```
(select [Name], [Age] from PeopleA
except
select [Name], [Age] from PeopleB)
union all
(select [Name], [Age] from PeopleB
except
select [Name], [Age] from PeopleA)
```

How to find missing, duplicate records. `Robert 34` in `PersonA` table for example below:

**PersonA**:

```
Name   | Age
-------------
John   | 45
Robert | 34
Adam   | 26
Robert | 34
```

**PersonB**:

```
Name   | Age
-------------
John   | 45
Robert | 34
Adam   | 26
```

Comment: I don't understand what your requirements are. Do you want to find records appearing in one table but not the other, or duplicate records in a single table?

Comment: @ZoffDino Dino I want to find records appearing in one table but not the other including duplicates. `Except` shows differences only if records are not duplicate. I need something like `'except all'` to find which relation is 1 to 1. For tables: `Table1: John 23, Mike 17, John 23` and `Table2: John 23, Mike 17` `except` does not shows difference, but this two tables are not the same. I need to find missing records so that when I will add these records to the tables, both tables will be the same, eg. `Table1: John 23, Mike 17, John 23` and `Table1: John 23, Mike 17, John 23`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to concat both tables and `Group By` with `Having` clause to find duplicates:

```
SELECT x.Name, x.Age, Cnt = Count(*) 
FROM (   
    SELECT a.Name, a.Age
    FROM PersonA a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b.Name, b.Age
    FROM PersonB b  
) x
GROUP BY x.Name, x.Age
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

---

According to your clarification in the comment, you could use following query to find all name-age combinations in `PersonA` which are different in `PersonB`:

```
WITH A AS(
   SELECT a.Name, a.Age, cnt = count(*)
   FROM PersonA a
   GROUP BY a.Name, a.Age
),
B AS(
   SELECT b.Name, b.Age, cnt = count(*)
   FROM PersonB b
   GROUP BY b.Name, b.Age
)
SELECT a.Name, a.Age
FROM A a LEFT OUTER JOIN B b
  ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Age = b.Age
WHERE a.cnt <> ISNULL(b.cnt, 0)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06ca1/4/0)

---

If you also want to find persons which are in `PersonB` but not in `PersonA` you should use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as Gordon Linoff has commented:

```
WITH A AS(
   SELECT a.Name, a.Age, cnt = count(*)
   FROM PersonA a
   GROUP BY a.Name, a.Age
),
B AS(
   SELECT b.Name, b.Age, cnt = count(*)
   FROM PersonB b
   GROUP BY b.Name, b.Age
)
SELECT Name = ISNULL(a.Name, b.Name), Age = ISNULL(a.Age, b.Age)
FROM A a FULL OUTER JOIN B b
  ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Age = b.Age
WHERE ISNULL(a.cnt, 0) <> ISNULL(b.cnt, 0)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9dcfe/2/0)

Comment: You are the fastest gun in the west! Certainly faster than me! :-) Anyway +1 as I was about to give basically the same answer.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Your solution find duplicate records: `John 45`, `Robert 34`, `Adam 46`. I want to find missing record - `Robert 34` in `PeopleB` table. This record exists in `PeopleA` twice but exists in `PeopleB` only once.

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . The `left join` should be `full outer join` so rows in the second table, but not the first, are also included in the result set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: good point, but i'm not sure if that is OP's requirement. However, i've included it in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like Tim's answer but you need to check in both tables if the records are missing. He is only checking if the records are missing in table A.  Try this to check if records are missing in either of the tables and how many times.

```
Select *, 'PersonB' MissingInTable, a.cnt - isnull(b.cnt,0) TimesMissing From 
(
Select *, count(1) cnt from PersonA group by Name, Age) A Left join 
(Select *, count(1) cnt from PersonB group by Name, Age) B
On a.age=b.age and a.name=b.name
where a.cnt>isnull(b.cnt,0)

Union All

Select *, 'PersonA' MissingInTable, b.cnt - isnull(a.cnt,0) TimesMissing From 
(
Select *, count(1) cnt from PersonA group by Name, Age) A Right join 
(Select *, count(1) cnt from PersonB group by Name, Age) B
On a.age=b.age and a.name=b.name
where b.cnt>isnull(a.cnt,0)
```

See demo here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/06020/13

Answer (score 0):

Add another `UNION ALL`!

## Code:

```
(SELECT [Name], [Age], 'Missing from B' AS [Type] from PeopleA
EXCEPT
SELECT [Name], [Age], 'Missing from B' AS [Type] from PeopleB)
UNION ALL
(SELECT [Name], [Age], 'Missing from A' as [Type] from PeopleB
EXCEPT
SELECT [Name], [Age], 'Missing from A' AS [Type] from PeopleA)
UNION ALL
SELECT [Name], [Age], 'Duplicate' AS [Type] FROM PeopleA INNER JOIN PeopleB ON PeopleA.Name = PeopleB.Name AND  
PeopleA.Age=PeopleB.Age
```